# How to identify EAAccessory Type is Printer, phone, computer, etc.?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, eaaccessory

My current project use bluetooth printer and i use EAAccessory framework for connect with the external device(printer). the problem is when i discover the bluetooth device, i get the all the devices paired with the iOS device. i need filter printers from the paired devices.

Comment: Maybe by looking the different property of an `EEAccessory`: `protocolStrings`, `name`, `manufacturer`...

Comment: Yeah we can get protocolStrings, manufacture. but i'm looking for get type. for a device can have several protocolStrings and for a manufacture can have several type of devices..

Answer (score 0):

I really do not think this is possible. If you want exact information on the actual type of the bluetooth device connected, such as whether it is a printer or a wireless headset, the EAAccessory framework will not be able to deduce this for you nor is it really EAAccessory's job. All the EAAccessory framework will give you is very basic metadata information on the currently connected devices, generally speaking you can use some combination of the meta data, such as [name, protocol string] OR [manufacturer, name] to identify what you have connected to.

If you need any richer metadata like what you are asking, you need to directly ask the device yourself, which means the device should have some API's available for you to communicate with it. From my personal experience though, the information returned and boxed into an EAAccessory framework is more than enough for me to understand the device I am connecting to, specific type information will than be deduced off of that in code. If you want dynamic reader type info, that is tough and you will need to query the device for that info yourself once establishing a logical session.